# Как поставить фильтр на колонну vba?

Tags: vba

Есть макро функция, запустив которую на ячейке C2 появляется сортировка.  В нете искал но так и не нашел, ну типа нажал  на треугольник и выбираешь из списка группы, после того как выбрал эксель показывает всех кто находятся в данной группе, все остальные стираются....я что-то не допонимаю как это сделать

Comment: Дал ответ по установке фильтра обычными инструментами, так как вопрос о макрофункции непонятен. Она точно есть и фильтр устанавливается с ее применением? Нужно показать код функции. ____ Выбор группы - остальные стираются... А если нужно выбрать другую - данных уже нет? Опишите задачу точнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установка фильтра без применения VBA.

Выделить данные, установить **фильтр**:

Закладка *Данные-Фильтр*

Можно выделить только "шапку таблицы", но если в данных есть блоки, разделенные пустыми строками, то строки ниже первой пустой в фильтр не попадут.

Вариант фильтра - **умная таблица**:

выделить данные, закладка *Вставка-Таблица*. Диапазон данных превратится в отформатированную таблицу с фильтром.

Если фильтр нужно **установить макросом**, можно действия, описанные выше, записать макрорекодером:

вкладка *Разработчик-Запиcь_макроса* или

вкладка *Вид-Макросы-Запись_макроса*

Должно получиться что-то типа такого:

```
Sub Макрос1()
    Range("A1:C10").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Макрорекодер пишет лишнее, для установки фильтра диапазон выделять не обязательно:

```
Range("A1:C10").AutoFilter
```

Войти в редактор *VBA*:

нажать *Alt+F8-Войти* или *Alt+F11*

Comment: Ну как..объясню поподробнее, я ввыбрал группу из списка в фильтре( в колонке группы в перемешку), макрос убрал все лишнее оставив только ту группу, которую я выбрал, если я выбрал опять другую группу, то все остальные группы, не совпадающие, пропадают а остается только та группе в колонке которую я выбрал, так будет понятнее

Comment: Почему считаете, что нужен макрос? Это можно сделать обычным фильтром. Название группы где находится?

Comment: макрос, потому-что задачу такую мне написали, а  я этот дураций фильтр не знаю как сделать, все остальное у меня, можно сказать что есть, названия групп находится в колонне C

Comment: Добавил в ответ...

Comment: Ты не знаешь случайно, как можно сделать "предложить сохранить данные листа" в тхт док. какой нить(пуолный путь к тхт....

Comment: 1. Вопрос не по теме. 2. Я с незнакомыми общаюсь на "Вы"

Comment: я знаю что не по теме, не могу создать новую, т.к. лимит исчерпан по вопросам, тогда я тоже на "Вы" буду